# Meaning of Divisibility in the definition of a relation

Tags: divisibility, order-theory

Consider {$ℝ+,≤$}, where "$≤$" defined as *"a is divisible by b"*. Is {$ℝ+,≤$} a Partially Ordered Set (POSET) ?
While checking for antisymmetric property,
***a≤b : a is divisible by b***

*The axioms for a non-strict partial order state that the relation ≤ is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive. That is, for all a, b, and c in P, it must satisfy:*

1. a ≤ a (reflexivity: every element is related to itself).
2. if a ≤ b and b ≤ a, then a = b (antisymmetry: two distinct elements cannot be related in both directions).
3. if a ≤ b and b ≤ c, then a ≤ c (transitivity: if a first element is related to a second element, and, in turn, that element is related to a third element, then the first element is related to the third element).

Does the above statement mean, we need to get the remainder as zero? 
My teacher said the definition of "divisibility" here is based on the concept of multiples and NOT on the concept of factors.

Can anyone please clarify this doubt? Please also prove that {$ℝ+,≤$} is NOT a POSET.

Comment: Presumably, since we're looking at positive numbers, $\Bbb R+$, **$a$ is divisible by $b$** means $b = ka$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$. Certainly there is no least element, but that is not an essential requirement.

Comment: I suggest you check the [three requirements for a Poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition) - adding them [into your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4094474/edit) would be good.

Comment: Consider (8/16)÷(40/36) and (40/36)÷(8/16) (where a=8/16 and b=40/36) can also be the case. Here clearly antisymmetric property fails. So it should be that {R+,≤} is not a POSET. what about this @Joffan?

Comment: neither of those numbers is divisible by the other in the sense I gave.

Comment: can we those two numbers which I considered divides each other? There is a difference between the two

Comment: Did you understand my first comment on what divisibility (probably) means here?

Comment: "$x$ is a factor of $y$" means exactly the same thing as "$y$ is a multiple of $x$".

Comment: Yes I understood your comment @Joffan. A clear cut answer with all the steps to this question would be helpful rather than continuing in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your teacher's hint that "the definition of "divisibility" here is based on the concept of multiples" we can say that ***a* is divisible by *b*** means that $\fbox{$a=kb$  for some $k\in \Bbb N$}$

Then for *reflexivity*: Test $a=ka$; take $k=1\in \Bbb N$, $\checkmark$
For *anti-symmetry*: If $a=kb$ with $k\neq1$ ($a,b$ distinct); then $b=\frac 1k a$ but $\frac 1k\not\in \Bbb N$, $\checkmark$
For *transitivity*: $a=kb$ and $b=jc$; so $a=kj\cdot c$ and $kj\in\Bbb N$, $\checkmark$

Thus the defined set is a POSet.

Comment: Thankyou @Joffan. But what if we consider the scalar to be from ℝ, like fractions? Then Anti-symmetry will fail right? Your proof is true for scalar k belonging to N

Comment: Well, what does divisibility even mean in such cases? It doesn't seem to be a well-defined relation.

Comment: @shreevaths6922 - Or if you prefer it's well-defined but trivial, everything is related to everything else.